# Python RegExp exception

Tags: python, regex

How do I split on all nonalphanumeric characters, EXCEPT the apostrophe?

```
re.split('\W+',text)
```

works, but will also split on apostrophes. How do I add an exception to this rule?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
re.split(r"[^\w']+",text)
```

Note the `w` is now lowercase, because it represents all alphanumeric characters (note that that includes the underscore). The character class `[^\w']` refers to anything that's *not* (`^`) either alphanumeric (`\w`) or an apostrophe.

Answer (score 2):

```
re.split(r"[^\w']+",text)
```

By starting a character class with `^`, it inverts the definition, so `[^\w']` is the inverse of `[\w']`, which would match an alphanumeric/underscore/apostrophe.

Answer (score 0):

The answers here don't work, as 'quoted' words will not be stripped of their apostrophes.

What works for me is

```
re.split(r"\W'+|^'+|'+\W|'$|[^\w']+", text)
```

i.e. remove:

apostrophe(s) after non-word  OR
apostrophe(s) at line start   OR
apostrophe(s) before non-word OR
the current solution